# Region of interest in

Tags: roi, jpeg2000

I'm a developing an application using jasper library and i need to encode ROI some ROI (region of interest).
I read in the jasper official website https://www.ece.uvic.ca/~frodo/jasper/ that, only the decoder support ROI.
But i saw in the jpc codec source code  https://github.com/mdadams/jasper/blob/master/src/libjasper/jpc/jpc_cs.h a field call "roishift".

Did someone know what it is for?

Thank you for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

`jasper` is a dead project. It is no longer consider an [active](https://jpeg.org/jpeg2000/software.html) reference JPEG 2000 implementation, why would anyone use `japser` these days ?

[OpenJPEG](http://www.openjpeg.org/) does implement the simple ROI *upshift a whole component*, if you can pick an active JPEG 2000 implementation.

Comment: Thank you for your answer !